# How to compare 2 requests in Postman

Tags: http, postman

I would like to compare 2 requests sent by postman. In the documentation of postman I only found information about comparing 2 repsonses. do you know how to compare 2 requests?

Comment: It depends what you're defining 'request'? The body, the method, the Headers, the URL, the Params, all of it?

Comment: Thanks for asking. I would like to comapre all the data which are contained in the requests.

Answer (score 0):

I come up with this way:

1. Open request tab
2. Click upright "Code" button (icon `</>`  )
3. Click "Copy" button to the right
4. Paste content to any diff tool, i.e. WinMerge
5. Do the same for the second request and make sure code snippet format is the same

Now you can see difference in diff tool